# bootstrap 4 cards width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I cant seem to get a card to stretch across the whole width of a col-md-6 column unless there is enough text in the card to push it to full width.  However, I would like it to be full width of the col-md-6 column even with no text.

If I uncomment that `<p>` tag then it fits the width perfectly, but I need to make it full width even with little to no text.

```html
<div class='col-md-6 jobs_index_middle_panels'>
      <div class="row">

            
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
      <!--<p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>-->

    </div>
  </div>        


    </div> <!--/.row -->
 </div> <!-- ./col-md-6 -->
```

Answer (score 9):

The card should be directly inside the `col-*`, and the `col-*` should be inside the `.row`...

https://www.codeply.com/go/tBl8MZOn7i

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 jobs_index_middle_panels">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```